# Difficulty handling return from Ajax call with js and prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am trying to insert an li containing a select after others within a ul, with the data in the options of the select obtained from a database via Ajax, and it's not working.

With apologies in advance for the length...

I retired a few years ago from web development, where I used Prototype quite a bit in the later years. I'm somewhat rusty now, but I'm trying to do some development for purely personal use. It won't be on the open web, just on our local server. It's all been going fine (if slowly!), but now I've hit a brick wall with Ajax.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I have a form with one or more selects, each within its own li, all in the one ul.
- Each select contains the same list of items from a table in a MySQL database.
- The last select has nothing selected and has the class "addselect".
- The idea is that if I select something from that last select, an onChange event is triggered which calls an Ajax script to add a new select (containing the same items). This is set up on page load in a "document.observe ('dom:loaded', function()..." at the top of the javascript file.
- Each select has a sequential name and id, eg 'name="country[0]" id="country_0"', the next country[1] and country_1, and so on. The newly created select would have the next name and id in sequence.
  I hope that all makes some sense.

So...
The handler function set up in 'dom:loaded...' gets the next index number for the name and id of the new select, and sends this ('entryindex') and the name of the table to search ('list') to the Ajax script, and off we go:

```
var pars = 'list=' + list + '&entryindex=' + newIndex;
var url = base + 'ajaxgetmenu';

// send request to do the business
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request (url, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: pars,
    onSuccess: function (req) {
        var xml = req.responseText;
        ...
```

This far, everything is hunkydory. The Resources tab in Safari's Web Inspector shows exactly the correct result - a nice new select with the correct name and contents - under 'XHRs'. So I know the script is being called and is operating correctly. But where it falls over is with what comes next:

```
        var newhtml = xml.getElementsByTagName('newhtml')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

This is taken from a script I developed back in my professional days which I know worked perfectly. But something is failing here, cuz it don't work! If I put an alert in ('ok') before this line, it pops up, but if I put it after this line it doesn't. And yet no errors are reported. And of course the next line doesn't work either:

```
        $('thisid').up('ul').insert (newhtml);
```

(And I know "$('thisid')" is right because I put that in an alert to check it.)

So I simplified it. I abandoned XML and made the result plain text instead, to be inserted verbatim. Again, the script produces a perfect result in Safari's Web Inspector, but even when newhtml is plain text (and I skip the xml.getElementsByTagName line altogether), it fails. And again, an alert before the insert line works, but not one after it. Indeed, I can put newhtml in the alert and it shows up just right (not all of it in Safari, where I guess it's just too long, but it's all there in Firefox).

I've tried everything I can think of, so if anyone has any wisdom on this I'd be very grateful indeed. It's probably something dead obvious staring me in the face...

In response to bergi:

Because what I'm trying to do doesn't work there's no change in the DOM before and after execution. Here's the relevant bit:

```
<ul id="country">
    <li><label>Countries:</label>
        <select class="finput addselect" name="country[0]" id="country_0">
            <options...
        </select>
    <li><label></label>
        <select class="finput addselect" name="country[1]" id="country_1">
            <options...
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The onChange applies to #country_1, and the new select should be inserted after that, so up('ul') should do it, right? I tried up(1) and that didn’t work either. I tried just inserting 'test' and that didn’t work...

Comment: So the ajax request is working, the part you have a problem with is only `.up('ul').insert (newhtml);`? Then please show us how your DOM looks at the moment of the execution. Are you getting no error messages?

Comment: Nope, no error messages at all. It's possible I'm not looking in the right place for them, but neither Firefox's Web Developer nor Safari's Web Inspector shows anything untoward. Forgive my ignorance (I did say I was rusty!) but by showing you my DOM do you mean the generated html source code (Firefox's 'View Selection Source')? There's a lot of it. Or should I edit it down to the relevant sections?

Comment: Actually, when you say the part I have trouble with is only .up('ul').insert (newhtml);, that's not strictly true. That’s after I abandoned XML. Before that the same problem occurred at the xml.getElementsByTagName line.

Comment: Yeah, I mean checking that the elements you target do actually exist and the line is not a no-op. Does running `$('thisid').up('ul').insert("test");` from the console do anything? If yes, I'd suggest stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: Sorry - needed a cup of tea! Actually, because what I'm trying to do doesn't work there's no change in the DOM before and after execution. Here's the relevant bit:

Comment: Because what I'm trying to do doesn't work there's no change in the DOM before and after execution. Here's the relevant bit:

 <ul id="country">
  <!-- li and select with id country_0 here -->
  <li><label></label>
   <select class="finput addselect" name="country[1]" id="country_1">
    <options...
   </select>
  </li>
 </ul>

The onChange applies to #country_1, and the new select should be inserted after that, so up('ul') should do it, right? I tried up(1) and that didn’t work either. I tried just inserting 'test' and that didn’t work...

Comment: I see - sorry, misunderstood (I am new here!) I'll edit the question. That'll make it much clearer.

Comment: Quick question - do you know whether there’s some limit to the length of a string that can be returned via Ajax, and whether it can contain carriage returns, tabs or whatever? What I’m returning here is politely formatted and indented html with 76 options in the select.

Comment: No, there's no practical limit, and it doesn't matter what characters it includes.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I suspected. But I'll leave this discussion for now because I'm having a rethink: I'll get the Ajax just to return the raw data in XML form and the JS can build the HTML. Thanks for your help, anyway - if nothing else it's got me thinking differently. I'll let you know!

Comment: Bergi, if you're still onto this, I solved the Ajax part but still can't insert the results into my code. I've opened a new thread on this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741277/problem-with-scope-when-inserting-results-of-ajax-call-into-page-code